# Code works; search and display all images from folder and all subfolders BUT how can I exclude a subfolder?

Tags: php, for-loop

I have the following code which displays file names in a specified folder (/images/) and all its sub-folders.

But how can I exclude a sub-folder?

ie. I dont want it to search and find images in the folder within the directory called /images/dont-search-here/

```
    $scan_it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("images/" . $this->item->extraFields->PropertyID->value . "");

      foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($scan_it) as $file) {
        if (strtolower(substr($file, -4)) == ".jpg" &&
            strtolower(substr($file, -4)) == ".jpg") {

            echo '<div><img src="'.$file .'" alt="" />'."</div>";
        }
     }
```

EDIT: Thanks Hanky! Could anyone possibly assist on implementing that on the example code I gave?

Comment: Thanks! Could anyone possibly assist on implementing that on the example code I gave?